# How to get a document from firestore in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've tried many methods such as

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(dynamicDocID).get()
const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(dynamicDocID)
```

as well as many other and keep getting undefined or a promise that never seems to be resolved

Cant seem to find proper docs on this if anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Cloud Functions for Firebase are written in Node.js, have a look at the Node.js examples in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js).

Based on that:

```
const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(dynamicDocID)
const document = await docRef.get()
console.log(document.id, document.data())
```

Or if you can't use `await`:

```
const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(dynamicDocID)
return docRef.get().then((document) => {
  console.log(document.id, document.data())
})
```

Comment: Await dint word. said it wasn't an async function    Second method worked.     Quick question, why do i need the "return" for the second method?      Thanks so much! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you can't use `async`/`await`, you need to explicitly return a promise, which is what the second code snippet in my answer does.